# Accessing Aframe events in Angular

Tags: angular, aframe

I have a basic Aframe example which I am able to render in my Angular app. I am also able to bind data from the ts file into the aframe entities. What I am unable to do is to listen to events and do something in my ts file.

Below is my ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
const aframe = (window as any).AFRAME;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  ngOnInit() {
    aframe.registerComponent('rotation-reader', {
      tick: function () {
        console.log("Hello World!")
        console.log(this.el.object3D.rotation);
        console.log(this.el.object3D.position);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

This is part of my code in html:

```
<a-entity id="camera" camera="active: true" wasd-controls position="0 2 -2" rotation-header look-controls></a-entity>
```

Currently, nothing gets printed on the console even if I rotate or move around. Even if I can get some examples of any event handler ( for example, listening to click events on an entity ), even that would be of great help. Thanks!

Comment: Hard to tell without code to run. I recommend https://glitch.com/~aframe. FWIW your component name and HTML attribute don't match. `rotation-header` vs. `rotation-reader`

Comment: @DiegoMarcos, thanks. Let me cross check it again.